# Display the result of a calculation initiated by an event in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have a quite simple problem in ASP.NET, which I already encountered in different forms but I never found an answer to it.

The problem is that I want to do some calculations in response to a Postback event (e.g. `OnClick` event of a button), which I then want to show in a `GridView` with a `DataObjectSource`.

The problem is that the page life cicle wants to fill the `DataObjectSource`, before executing the `OnClick` event. 
I see why this order makes sense in general, but I don't know how I can change my code so that it works. Depending on whether I initialize the result variable, I either get a null Pointer exception or just an empty table.

Here some relevant parts of the code:

```
Page_Load() 
{
    GridView1.Visible = IsPostBack;
}

DataTable result;

Btn_Click()
{
    // do some calculations
    result = ...;
}

GetData()
{
    return result;
}
```

As `GetData()` is called before `Btn_Click()`, the table is empty (or even `null` here).

Comment: Where are you setting the GridView DataSource? If the datasource is set prior to the calculation being finished, you can reset the datasource and/or call the `GridView1.DataBind()` method to rebind the gridview to the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GridView.DataBind()` method :

```
Page_Load() {
    GridView1.Visible = IsPostBack;
}

DataTable result;

Btn_Click() {
    // do some calculations
    result = ...;

    // calculations finished... bind the gridview
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

GetData() {
    return result;
}
```

This will re-bind the GridView to the datasource object once the calculations have been completed.